# Preserve tabs from textarea in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want a textarea of which I can save the content in PHP and display it later again with exactly the same format.
With the same format I mean to preserve tabs.

If my textarea contains:

```
xxxxx     test
x         test
```

My HTML must contain:

```
xxxxx     test
x         test
```

But in most cases it contains:

```
xxxxx          test
x         test
```

I am using `white-space: pre` but that doesn't fully work.

This is my test-code:

```php
<?php
    $output = "";
    if (isset($_POST['btnSend'])) {
        // Here we would save to database etc...
        //...

        $output = $_POST['txt'];
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea id="txt" name="txt"></textarea>
    <br><input type="submit" name="btnSend" value="send">
</form> 

<p style="white-space:pre;" id="output"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($output) ?></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key == 'Tab') {
    e.preventDefault();
    var start = this.selectionStart;
    var end = this.selectionEnd;

    // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, start) +
      "\t" + this.value.substring(end);

    // put caret at right position again
    this.selectionStart =
      this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
  }
});
</script>
```

Input:

```
xxxxxxxx        rofl
xxxxx           looodwjwiw
```

Nicely formats.

Input:

```
xxxxxxxx    rofl
xx          looodwjwiw
```

Fails.

How can I better preserve tabs in PHP?

**Edit:** This issue only exists in Safari. The problem exists in all browsers when using a font-family like Roboto.

Comment: Have you tried the `<pre>` element? Seems to do the job when I test it.

Comment: `<pre>` gives the same problem. Note that I'm already using `white-space: pre`.

Comment: Interesting. Literal `<pre>` and just the `white-space:pre` styling give different results for me. Styling reproduces your problem, while the element produces the desired behaviour. Is there any other CSS in play here?

Comment: There is not other CSS in play. Can you inspect element the pre-tag? It is just a div using `white-space: pre`. Should not give a difference.

Comment: @El_Vanja The issue only consists in Safair.

Comment: Yeah, right after your comment about the `<pre>` being converted to `<div>`, I suspected browser-specific behaviour. I would suggest editing your question and tagging `safari`. PHP isn't relevant to the issue, it's all about the way the browser interprets and displays HTML.

Comment: Edit again. The issue exists in all browsers using the Roboto font.

Comment: Keep in mind, that tabs don't have a fixed width. The width could vary from browser to browser, from OS to OS, and maybe other factors. Also the purpose of tabs (in ASCII) is not to display table-like data. Generally you should avoid using them in this way. What is your bigger picture? Why are you doing this?

Comment: @RoToRa An administrator can give in a product description for products in a catalogus. This description exists mostly out of paragraphs. But sometimes the admin wants to list specifications and format them using tabs. There is not really a structure. But it seems to work with a font like Arial though.

Comment: That's a bad approach. They should only input data and not worry about the way it's presented. The best case would be have them input the specs with a delimiter (something like `price: 300`), so you can take the name and value of a spec separately and put them in a table or something.

Comment: Use an html input field such as CKEditor and let the admin insert tables or definition lists.